Replace recessed light with surface-mounted light
I'm trying to change some recessed lights with some surface-mounted lights. I'm doing this because the recessed lights are just not bright enough for us. The lights I'm replacing them with are completely made of plastic. The recessed lights are 4 inches.
The original plan was to take the 5-inch plastic mounting plate and just anchor it into the ceiling on top of the can. The problem is that the hole for the recessed light is a bit too big for me to do this. I was thinking of using these 6-inch metal bars to mount the plastic mount to the ceiling across the can opening. I know when there is metal involved, the fixture needs to be grounded. I don't see a grounding wire in the recessed light can.
Does the bar actually need to be grounded? Is wrapping it in electrical tape a bad idea? Should I use something plastic instead? Is there a better option for mounting it that won't break the bank?
Any ideas or advice is welcome.
I've attached pictures of the can, the bar, and the mounting plate




Protip: A recessed light is a flush-mounted light. What you're asking about is a surface mounted light. (The confusion stems from marketing departments' misuse of the term "flush", which does not mean "tight to".)

Welcome. Please take the [tour].

Have you tried simply using the brightest bulbs that will fit the existing fixtures?

Or different trims that allow wider light dispersion? I can't imagine modern LED bulbs being inadequate in such a way that these new lights are an improvement.

At the other end of the gray wire with the orange connector there will be a junction box attached to the can.
The can is only good for 8.2W, so if your new light needs more than that you'll definitely need to replace the can with a new junction box and mount your light to that.

Looks like the light we want is 24w. Is there a junction box you recommend? Do you have any tutorials/videos you recommended on swapping out the can with a junction box? Thank you!

Any ordinary metal junction box will work fine - it is just the "integrated" junction boxes with light fixtures (which you likely have but we don't know for sure) that are extremely limited both in rated wattage and in space for wires.
